# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found error java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, client-server, java-threads

Keep getting this error
"java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found error java" 
and searched through code so many times and cant see to find problems heres my files can anyone help?
Am currently doing this as an assignment and am trying to transfer it from unthreaded to threaded and in the process came up with this error!!

```html
This is the Client class

package Client;

import core.Email;
import core.EmailServiceDetails;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class EmailClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            // Step 1 (on consumer side) - Establish channel of communication
           Socket dataSocket = new Socket("localhost", EmailServiceDetails.LISTENING_PORT); 
           
           // Step 3) Build output and input objects
            OutputStream out = dataSocket.getOutputStream();
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out));

            InputStream in = dataSocket.getInputStream();
            Scanner input = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(in));
           
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String message = "";
            while(!message.equals(EmailServiceDetails.END_SESSION))
            {
                displayMenu();
                int choice = getNumber(keyboard);
                String response = "";
                if(choice >=0 && choice < 3)
                {
                    switch (choice)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            message = EmailServiceDetails.END_SESSION;
                            
                            // Send message
                            output.println(message);
                            output.flush();
                            
                            response = input.nextLine();
                            if(response.equals(EmailServiceDetails.SESSION_TERMINATED))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Session ended.");
                            }
                            
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            message = sendEmail(keyboard);

                            // Send message
                            output.println(message);
                            output.flush();
                            
                            // Get response
                            response = input.nextLine();
                            
                            if(response.equals(EmailServiceDetails.SUCCESSFUL_ADD))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Email sent successfully");
                            }
                            else if(response.equals(EmailServiceDetails.UNSUCCESSFUL_ADD))
                            {
                                System.out.println("Sorry, the email could not be sent at this time.");
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            message = viewUnread(keyboard);
                            
                            // Send message
                            output.println(message);
                            output.flush();
                            
                            // Get response
                            response = input.nextLine();
                            if(response.equals(EmailServiceDetails.NO_UNREAD))
                            {
                                System.out.println("No unread mails found for that account.");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                ArrayList<Email> unreadMails = EmailServiceDetails.parseEmailList(response);
                                System.out.println("Unread Emails:");
                                for(Email e: unreadMails)
                                {
                                    System.out.println(e);
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    if(response.equals(EmailServiceDetails.UNRECOGNISED))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, that request cannot be recognised.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Please select an option from the menu");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the Email system.");
            dataSocket.close();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: "  + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void displayMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("0) Exit");
        System.out.println("1) Send an email");
        System.out.println("2) View all unread mails");
    }
    
    public static int getNumber(Scanner keyboard)
    {
        boolean numberEntered = false;
        int number = 0;
        while(!numberEntered)
        {
            try{
                number = keyboard.nextInt();
                numberEntered = true;
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
                keyboard.nextLine();
            }
        }
        keyboard.nextLine();
        return number;
    }

    public static String sendEmail(Scanner keyboard)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the sender of this email:");
        String sender = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        // Get recipient information
        String anotherRecipient = "Y";
        ArrayList<String> recipients = new ArrayList();
        while(anotherRecipient.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the recipient's email address:");
            String recipient = keyboard.nextLine();
            recipients.add(recipient);
            
            System.out.println("Would you like to add another recipient? ('Y' for yes and 'N' for no)");
            anotherRecipient = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the email subject:");
        String subject = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the message body:");
        String body = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        // Get attachment information
        ArrayList<String> attachments = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println("Would you like to enter an attachment ('Y' to add and 'N' to continue)");
        String anotherAttachment = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        while(anotherAttachment.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the attachment information:");
            String attachment = keyboard.nextLine();
            attachments.add(attachment);
            
            System.out.println("Would you like to add another attachment? ('Y' for yes and 'N' to Continue)");
            anotherAttachment = keyboard.nextLine();
        }
        
        long timestamp = new Date().getTime();
        String response = null;
        Email e = null;
        if(attachments.size() > 0)
        {
            e = new Email(sender, recipients, subject, body, timestamp, attachments);
        }
        else
        {
            e = new Email(sender, recipients, subject, body, timestamp);
        }
        
        response = EmailServiceDetails.ADD_MAIL + EmailServiceDetails.COMMAND_SEPARATOR + EmailServiceDetails.formatEmail(e);
        return response;
    }
  
    public static String viewUnread(Scanner keyboard)
    {
        
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the email account you wish to see unread mail for:");
        String recipient = keyboard.nextLine();
        
        String response = EmailServiceDetails.VIEW_UNREAD + EmailServiceDetails.COMMAND_SEPARATOR + recipient;
        return response;
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is Server
---------------

package Server;
import Server.Commands.Command;
import core.EmailServiceDetails;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmailServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            // Set up a connection socket for other programs to connect to
            ServerSocket listeningSocket = new ServerSocket(EmailServiceDetails.LISTENING_PORT);
            
            // Create the list of emails to be stored and worked with
            EmailStore emails = new EmailStore();
            
            boolean continueRunning = true;
            int threadCount = 0;
            
            while(continueRunning)
            {
                // Step 2) wait for incoming connection and build communications link
                Socket dataSocket = listeningSocket.accept();
                
                threadCount++;
                System.out.println("The server has now accepted " + threadCount + " clients");

                // Step 3) Build thread 
                //         Thread should be given:
                //              1) a group to be stored in
                //              2) a name to be listed under
                //              3) a socket to communicate through
                //              4) Any extra information that should be shared
                
                EmailThread newClient = new EmailThread (emails, dataSocket.getInetAddress()+"", dataSocket,threadCount);
                
                newClient.start();
            }
            listeningSocket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is ServerThread
---------------

package Server;


import Server.Commands.Command;
import Server.EmailStore;
import core.EmailServiceDetails;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class EmailThread extends Thread {

    private Socket dataSocket;
    private Scanner input;
    private PrintWriter output;
    private int number;
    private EmailStore emails;

    public EmailThread(EmailStore emails,String name, Socket dataSocket, int number) {

   
        try {
            // Save the data socket used for communication between the thread and the Client
            this.dataSocket = dataSocket;
            // Save the id of the thread to identify output
// Save the id of the thread to identify output
            this.number = number;
            
            input = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(this.dataSocket.getInputStream()));
            // Create the stream for writing to the Client
            output = new PrintWriter(this.dataSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occurred while setting up connection links for a thread: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        {
            String incomingMessage = "";
            String response;
            try {
                while (!incomingMessage.equals(EmailServiceDetails.END_SESSION)) {
                    // Wipe the response to make sure we never use an old value
                    response = null;

                    // take in information from the client
                    incomingMessage = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Received message: " + incomingMessage);
                    // Break up information into components
                    String[] components = incomingMessage.split(EmailServiceDetails.COMMAND_SEPARATOR);

                    // Confirm that the command was correctly formatted 
                    // Did it include more than just the command text?
                    if (components.length > 1) {
                        CommandFactory factory = new CommandFactory();
                        // Figure out which command was sent by the client
                        // I.e. what does the client want to do?
                        Command command = factory.createCommand(components[0]);
                        
                        // Take the remaining text the client sent (i.e. all the information provided)
                        // and execute the requested action (e.g. store the new mail, get all sent mails etc)
                        response = command.createResponse(components[1], emails);
                    } else if (components[0].equals(EmailServiceDetails.END_SESSION)) {
                        response = EmailServiceDetails.SESSION_TERMINATED;
                    } else {
                        // If information was missing, set the response to inform the
                        // client that the command wasn't recognised
                        response = EmailServiceDetails.UNRECOGNISED;
                    }

                    // Send back the computed response
                    output.println(response);
                    output.flush();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("An exception occurred while communicating with client #" + number + ": " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    // Shut down connection
                    System.out.println("\n* Closing connection with client #" + number + "... *");
                    dataSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to disconnect: " + e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

   
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is EmailStore
---------------
package Server;

import core.Email;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class EmailStore 
{
    private ArrayList<Email> emailList = new ArrayList();
    
    public boolean addMail(Email newEmail)
    {
        return emailList.add(newEmail);
    }
    
    public boolean removeMail(Email mailToBeDeleted)
    {
        return emailList.remove(mailToBeDeleted);
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Email> findEmailByRecipient(String recipient)
    {
        ArrayList<Email> results = new ArrayList();
        
        results = (ArrayList<Email>) emailList.stream()
                // Find all emails whose recipients list contents the specified recipient
                .filter(email -> email.getRecipients().contains(recipient))
                // Collect the results back into a List (this does not return an ArrayList, so need to cast)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return results;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Email> findEmailBySender(String sender)
    {
        ArrayList<Email> results = new ArrayList();
        
        results = (ArrayList<Email>) emailList.stream()
                // Find all emails matching the specified sender
                .filter(email -> email.getSender().equals(sender))
                // Collect the results back into a List (this does not return an ArrayList, so need to cast)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return results;
    }
    
    // Methods to mark emails as read
    // Provide a version that marks multiple mails as read AND a version that
    // marks a single email as read
    public void markMultipleAsRead(ArrayList<Email> emails)
    {
        for(Email e : emails)
        {
            markAsRead(e);
        }
    }
    
    public void markAsRead(Email e)
    {
        int index = emailList.indexOf(e);
        if(index != -1)
        {
            Email storedMail = emailList.get(index);
            storedMail.markAsRead(true);
        } 
    }
    
    // Methods to mark emails as spam
    // Provide a version that marks multiple mails as spam AND a version that
    // marks a single email as spam
    
    public void markAsSpam(Email e)
    {
        int index = emailList.indexOf(e);
        if(index != -1)
        {
            Email storedMail = emailList.get(index);
            storedMail.markAsSpam(true);
        } 
    }
    
    public void markMultipleAsSpam(ArrayList<Email> emails)
    {
        for(Email e : emails)
        {
            markAsSpam(e);
        }
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Email> findUnreadEmailByRecipient(String recipient)
    {
        ArrayList<Email> results = new ArrayList();
        
        results = (ArrayList<Email>) emailList.stream()
                // Find all emails whose recipients list contents the specified recipient AND the email is not unread
                .filter(email -> email.getRecipients().contains(recipient) && !email.isRead())
                // Collect the results back into a List (this does not return an ArrayList, so need to cast)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        return results;
    }
}
-------
Help Appreciated

 - 


----------
```

Help would be great appreciated as the frustration levels are at a high!!

Comment: [java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found](//stackoverflow.com/q/7209110)

Comment: Mate, this is by far too much code. Can you narrow it down a bit? What action/method causes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a wild guess but in case 1 of the switch statement of the main method you are calling the input.nextLine() scanner which it might not contain information at that time. It is possible that you have to check if data arrived by using the hasNext() method first.

Also in the last method when you are collecting the email classes you don't really need to cast. It can be done like this:

```
results = emailList.stream()
                   .filter(email -> email.getRecipients().contains(recipient) && !email.isRead())
                   .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```